# SQL-Creating Table

Tags: sql, subquery, create-table

I am stuck with this question. I know table can be created with the select statement.

```
CREATE TABLE new_orders (ordr_id,order_date DEFAULT SYSDATE,cus_id) 
AS 
Select order_id.order_date,customer_id FROM Orders;
```

Which statement would be true regarding the above question ?

1. The NEW_ORDERS table would not get created beacuse the default value cannot be specified in the column definition.
2. The NEW_ORDERS table would get created and only the NOT NULL constraint define on the specified columnns would be passed to the new table.
3. The NEW_ORDERS table would not get created because the column names in the CREATE TABLE command and the SELECT clause do not match.
4. The NEW_ORDERS table would get created and all the constraints defined on the specified columns in the orders table would be passed to new Table.

I think correct answer should be 3, but it's wrong. The correct answer according to my book is 2. I don't get it how?

Comment: is it MCQ ?????

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: you could have tried yourself ?

Comment: have tried and that's why i think answer is 3.But my book is saying that correct answer for this MCQ is 2.

Comment: @ravi Yeah it's MCQ.

Comment: @RabiyaEmrAan I don't know, what books says, but if you tried and got error. Then, in my opinion stop following that book or It might be typo.

Comment: @ravi i know it can be a typo,wanted 2 opinion.

Comment: This depends on the DBMS you are using. Answer 2. would be correct for Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks !

Comment: Regarding which above question, nowhere above you have stated a question..

Answer (score 0):

The answer should not be 3. Because in the `select` statement, you are taking values from `Orders` table. So you will use the column names of that table. Selecting value from there, you are inserting it into `new_orders`. So, the column names don't have to be same because they are different tables.